# What is the difference between Converting and Unboxing?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-3.5, expression-trees, dynamic-language-runtime

In the DLR's LINQ Expressions, what is the difference between this:

```
Expression.Convert(SomeVariableExpression, typeof(T));
```

and this:

```
Expression.Unbox(SomeVariableExpression, typeof(T));
```

The documentation on this seems a bit sketchy.

And more to the point, which one of these is equivalent to this C# code:

```
(ClassA)InstanceOfClassB
```

Where ClassB has an implicit or explicit operator to cast to ClassA?

Comment: Sorry, this got double posted.  I've deleted the other one though.  :-)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32158399/1127114) for a specific example of when it's necessary to use Unbox instead of Convert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the main difference is that `Epression.Unbox` is only needed for explicit unboxing of a value type off the heap.  `Expression.Convert` is the method you would want to use to hook into a user-defined conversion (whether implicit or explicit).

See [`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx):

> If either expression.Type or type is
>   a user-defined type that defines an
>   implicit or explicit conversion
>   operator, the `MethodInfo` that
>   represents that operator is the
>   implementing method.

and also:

> If either expression.Type or type is a
>   reference type and an explicit boxing,
>   unboxing, or reference conversion
>   exists from expression.Type to type,
>   the implementing method is
>   null.

Answer (score 4):

The important thing Unbox is that it gives you the address of the boxed value.  This ensures that you can call a method on the unboxed value.  If that method mutates the value type then it's mutating the boxed version instead of a new copy.  If you merely did Convert then you'd actually have made a copy of the boxed value type and then calling a method on it would mutate the copy and not the original value.

Answer (score 2):

In general, boxing takes a value type and wraps it in an object.  Unboxing does the reverse.  You can think of this as boxing takes a register or stack value and puts it on the heap, returning a pointer to that value.  Unboxing takes an object on the heap and puts it into a register or stack frame.  The underlying datatype stays the same.

Convert changes one datatype into another.

Answer (score 1):

Expression.Convert is the equivalent of doing a cast.

Comment: Unboxing is the process of getting a value type that has been previously boxed (in other words the value from the stack is copied to the heap and a reference to the new object is pushed onto the stack).