# Using FieldInfo.SetValue vs LINQ expressions to set a field in a struct

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, linq-expressions

I want to set private fields using LINQ expressions. I have this code:

```
//parameter "target", the object on which to set the field `field`
ParameterExpression targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "target");

//parameter "value" the value to be set in the `field` on "target"
ParameterExpression valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

//cast the target from object to its correct type
Expression castTartgetExp = Expression.Convert(targetExp, type);

//cast the value to its correct type
Expression castValueExp = Expression.Convert(valueExp, field.FieldType);

//the field `field` on "target"
MemberExpression fieldExp = Expression.Field(castTartgetExp, field);

//assign the "value" to the `field` 
BinaryExpression assignExp = Expression.Assign(fieldExp, castValueExp);

//compile the whole thing
var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>> (assignExp, targetExp, valueExp).Compile();
```

This compiles a delegate that takes two objects, the target and the value:

```
setter(someObject, someValue);
```

The `type` variable specifies the `Type` of the target, and the `field` variable is a `FieldInfo` that specifies the field to be set.

This works great for reference types, but if the target is a struct, then this thing will pass the target as a copy to the setter delegate and set the value on the copy, instead of setting the value on the original target like I want. (At least that is what I think is going on.)

On the other hand,

```
field.SetValue(someObject, someValue);
```

works just fine, even for structs.

Is there anything I can do about this in order to set the field of the target using the compiled expression?

Comment: As you cant use `ref`, the only way would be assign the return value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For value types, use [Expression.Unbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.unbox(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [Expression.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
//cast the target from object to its correct type
Expression castTartgetExp = type.IsValueType
    ? Expression.Unbox(targetExp, type)
    : Expression.Convert(targetExp, type);
```

Here's a demo: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9xYZhk)

---

**Q: The `setter` method doesn't have a `ref` parameter. How can it update the original struct?**

**A:** Although it's true that, without the `ref` keyword, value types are normally passed by value and thus copied, here the type of the `target` parameter is `object`. If the argument is a boxed struct, then a *reference* to the box is passed (by value) to the method.

Now, it's not possible using pure C# to mutate a boxed struct because a C# unboxing conversion always produces a copy of the boxed value. But it *is* possible using IL or Reflection:

```
public struct S { public int I; }

public void M(object o, int i)
{
    // ((S)o).I = i; // DOESN'T COMPILE
    typeof(S).GetField("I").SetValue(o, i);
}

public void N()
{
    S s = new S();
    object o = s; // create a boxed copy of s

    M(o, 1); // mutate o (but not s)
    Console.WriteLine(((S)o).I); // "1"
    Console.WriteLine(s.I);      // "0"

    M(s, 2); // mutate a TEMPORARY boxed copy of s (BEWARE!)
    Console.WriteLine(s.I);      // "0"
}
```

**Q: Why doesn't the setter work if the LINQ expression uses Expression.Convert?**

**A:** Expression.Convert compiles to the [`unbox.any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unbox_any(v=vs.110).aspx) IL instruction, which returns a *copy* of the struct referenced by `target`. The setter then updates this copy (which is subsequently discarded).

**Q: Why does Expression.Unbox fix the problem?**

**A:** Expression.Unbox (when used as the target of Expression.Assign) compiles to the [`unbox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unbox(v=vs.110).aspx) IL instruction, which returns a *pointer* to the struct referenced by `target`. The setter then uses the pointer to modify that struct directly.

Comment: This the problem. Not the answer.

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that the struct is passed into a lambda (and even untyped, it is not going to make a difference).

Comment: still, Im as curious as @leppie on why the valuetype is not copied when passing it into the delegate (?)

Comment: @leppie: I've updated my answer with a (hopefully) clear explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I cannot wrap my head round one thing, though:

In the demo, if I declare the variable as `object`, it works, but as `S`, it will fail. Could you please direct me towards an explanation for that?

Comment: @tethered.sun: If the variable `o` is declared as `S` rather than `object`, then `M(o, 1)` is equivalent to `M((object)o, 1)`, where `(object)o` represents a [boxing conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). The result of `(object)o` is a *temporary boxed copy* of `o`. This copy is mutated by `M` and then discarded, leaving the original `o` unchanged. In contrast, if `o` is declared as `object`, then `M(o, 1)` does not involve any boxing conversion or copying.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Thank you kindly. I am trying to implement my own custom binary serialisation and your solution is essential in speeding up reflexion-based member access.